# How to set device for specific operation in CNTK?

Tags: python, cntk

I have model in cntk which consists of an embedding layer and a following LSTM.  I would like to put the embedding lookup operation on CPU, and the rest of the network on GPU.
In tensorflow, I would do

```
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
```

What is the equivalent in cntk that I can wrap this into:

```
C.layers.Embedding(embedding_size)
```

Answer (score 1):

In CNTK, device control is over forward / backward passes of particular functions/networks, not individual operations. If you want to  execute a particular operation in CPU  and the rest in GPU you would have to do the following:

```
features = C.input_variable(input_dim)
labels = C.input_variable(label_dim)
embedding_input = C.input_variable(embedding_size, needs_gradient=True)
embedding = C.layers.Embedding(embedding_size)(features)
loss = rest_of_your_network(embedding_input, labels)
emb_state, embedding_value = embedding.forward({features: some_data}, keep_for_backward=set(embedding.output), device=C.cpu(), as_numpy=False)
loss_state, loss_value = loss.forward({embedding_input: embedding_value}, keep_for_backward=set(loss.output), device=C.gpu(0), as_numpy=False)
loss_grad_dict = loss.backward(loss_state, {loss.output: np.ones_like(loss_value)}, set(loss.parameters + [embedding_input]))
emb_grad_dict = embedding.backward(emb_state, {embedding.output: loss_grad_dict[embedding_input]}, set(embedding.parameters))
# use these dictionaries to update the parameters with a learner
```